# react error in propTypes

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a new app with React.

I created a new app as instructed on React webpage as follows:

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app my-app`

`cd my-app`

`npm start`

The installed React version is 15.5.4.

Then, a Dummy class is made in 'Dummy.js' file for studying:

```
import React from 'react';

class Dummy extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
   }
   propTypes : {
      name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
   }
}
```

And in App.js file, I added a line `<Dummy name="this is dummy class"/>`.

It works well but when I change the syntax as noted in React blog [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html),

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Dummy extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
   }
   Component.propTypes = {
      name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
   };
}
```

then, it return syntax error (unexpected token):

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out the reason?

Comment: just move out he proptypes declaration outside component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [React `propTypes` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for the expected way to declare `propTypes`:

```
class Dummy extends React.Component {}

Dummy.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

---

`create-react-app`'s [Babel config supports using the following syntax sugar](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which amounts to the same thing:

```
class Dummy extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }
}
```

---

Also, as per the docs, `React.PropTypes` is deprecated in favour of a separate `prop-types` package as of React v15.5:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

class Dummy extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }
}
```